# In Arrow S5E11 do they use Seattle as background

Tags: arrowverse, film-location, arrow

At 31 minutes and 15 seconds there is a shot of what apears to be the Seattle Space Needle all lit up blue.

[image]

Is this actually the Space Needle?

Comment: @AJ Considering the Space Needle is in Seattle (and argueably its most iconic architectural landmark) how do title and body *not* match? Since the show is filmed in Vancouver, BC, they could very well make the short trip across the border to Seattle if they need to visit another city (*Hub City* in-universe).

Comment: @BMWurm I didn't know that Space Needle is in Seattle (I am not USain)

Comment: @AJ No problem, neither am I. I only knew about the Needle from the title card of *Frasier* ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Is this actually the Space Needle?

## NO

Although *Arrow* & *The Flash* are filmed in the area (Pacific Northwest) this is not the Space Needle

It's the **Lookout Tower** in Vancouver which is where the shows are *actually filmed*.

[image]

The distinguising detail is the "spire" on top which is much smoother on the actual Space Needle

[image]

[image]